# jQuery Type Error in Firebug Console

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I tried to include a few jQuery plugin in my project i get too many errors in the firebug console. am not sure why they appear. I can also confirm that the jQuery lib has been loading as well.

I dont get these error when i run them on my template files. when i convert them into my cakePHP template i get so many javascript error.

I tried to debug each of the files but there seem to be no error with the same.

[image]

Comment: $.browser has been deprecated in the newest releases of jQuery - you need to use something else to get the desired effect.

Comment: The text in the screenshot is really too small to read, but the first thing I check if I'm getting errors when I have multiple plugins is that I'm using `noConflict()`. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/.

Comment: @EmmyS http://i.stack.imgur.com/uoIQc.png

Comment: What version of jquery are you using? Do all your plugins work with that version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using jQuery 1.9 or 2.0, `$.browser` was removed from the code. That could be it.

Comment: thanks i was trying to use the latest jQuery and if i did a fall back using the themes 1.7 version it works all fine

Answer (score 1):

Actually this usually happened, when you use library code with some wrong parameters actually this is not exception related to jQuery but the library you use. Put your code in:

```
try
  {
  //Run some code here
  }
catch(err)
  {
  //Handle errors here
  }
```

and use Jquery 1.8 as updated libraries removed `$.browser`:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
```